# Automation of images to PDF at District level

Tags: r, python-3.x, latex

I want create a PDF with 5 Images from 5 folder with text. First I want to read the district name from CSV file and  check the same file name in each folder. Second if the file name are matching, Make a PDF with the five images and CSV name as title for the PDF page and text which will be common for all the PDF. I want to give particular font and size, border for images, border for text also. I want to repeat for n number of districts. Is it possible with LaTeX or python?? Can anyone help me please, I am new to coding. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In LaTeX including graphics is done with: [`\includegraphics`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139401/how-to-use-graphicspath) and it's fairly straightforward.  You can find a number of examples on the linked page above that will walk you through setting the pathname to each of your folders as necessary.  There's also a good answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301494/how-to-use-includegraphics) about how to set multiple pathways in the declaration of your document.  As a general note, LaTeX will definitely be more flexible with making pdfs than either r or LaTeX because that's what it was built for.

Comment: Thank you. I will check the link.